# How can I lower the opacity of a game object in an array when a specific event occurs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For example, in my game, I want these small player icons to turn transparent when the player dies. I already have a function called `PlayerDead`, but when I put the game object in the function, I can't access the sprite renderer. I would preferably like to not attach my main script to the icon, but I really have no clue how to do it. For reference, `_checkForGameOver` is a counter to see how many times the player/enemy has died. When the player dies, a question mark in place of where the icon is destroyed, and the icon is instantiated in that spot. Here is a portion of the code from the main script:

```
public GameObject[] playerPrefab;
public GameObject[] enemyPrefab;
public GameObject[] icon;
public GameObject[] questionMarks;

public Transform playerSpawn;
public Transform enemySpawn;

public Transform topSpawn;
public Transform middleSpawn;
public Transform bottomSpawn;
public Transform topSpawnEnemy;
public Transform middleSpawnEnemy;
public Transform bottomSpawnEnemy;

Unit playerUnit;
Unit enemyUnit;

int randomIntPlayer;
int randomIntEnemy;

public bool playerPassDamage;

public BattleHUD playerHUD;
public BattleHUD enemyHUD;

public BattleState state;

public Button attackButton;
public Button passButtonDamage;
public Button healButton;
public Button passButtonResistance;
public GameObject playAgain;

public GameObject circleAttack;
public GameObject squareAttack;

public IconColor iconColor;

public Shake shake;

private int _checkForGameOverPlayer { get; set; } = 0;
private int _checkForGameOverEnemy { get; set; } = 0;


   void Start()
{
    shake = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ScreenShake").GetComponent<Shake>();
    state = BattleState.START;
    StartCoroutine(SetupBattle());
}


 IEnumerator SetupBattle()
{
    randomIntPlayer = Random.Range(0, playerPrefab.Length);
    GameObject playerGO = Instantiate(playerPrefab[randomIntPlayer], playerSpawn);
    playerUnit = playerGO.GetComponent<Unit>();

    if(randomIntPlayer == 0)
    {
      Instantiate(icon[0], topSpawn);
    }
    else if (randomIntPlayer == 1)
    {
      Instantiate(icon[1], topSpawn);
    }
    else if (randomIntPlayer == 2)
    {
        Instantiate(icon[2], topSpawn);
    }
    else if (randomIntPlayer == 3)
    {
        Instantiate(icon[3], topSpawn);
    }

    randomIntEnemy = Random.Range(0, enemyPrefab.Length);
    GameObject enemyGO = Instantiate(enemyPrefab[randomIntEnemy], enemySpawn);
    enemyUnit = enemyGO.GetComponent<Unit>(); 

    if (randomIntEnemy == 0)
    {
        Instantiate(icon[0], topSpawnEnemy);
    }
    else if (randomIntEnemy == 1)
    {
        Instantiate(icon[1], topSpawnEnemy);
    }
    else if (randomIntEnemy == 2)
    {
        Instantiate(icon[2], topSpawnEnemy);
    }
    else if (randomIntEnemy == 3)
    {
        Instantiate(icon[3], topSpawnEnemy);
    }

    playerUnit.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
    enemyUnit.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;

    playerHUD.SetHUD(playerUnit);
    enemyHUD.SetHUD(enemyUnit);

    playerPassDamage = false;
    didPlayerHeal = false;

    if (playerUnit.speed > enemyUnit.speed)
    {
        state = BattleState.PLAYERTURN;
        PlayerTurn();
    }

    else if (enemyUnit.speed > playerUnit.speed)
    {
        passButtonDamage.interactable = false;
        attackButton.interactable = false;
        healButton.interactable = false;
        passButtonResistance.interactable = false;
        state = BattleState.ENEMYTURN;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.2f);
        StartCoroutine(EnemyTurn());
    }
}

 public IEnumerator EnemyDead()
{
    _checkForGameOverEnemy++;

    if (_checkForGameOverEnemy == 1)
    {
        if (randomIntEnemy == 0)
        {

        }
        else if (randomIntEnemy == 1)
        {

        }
        else if (randomIntEnemy == 2)
        {

        }
        else if (randomIntEnemy == 3)
        {

        }
    }

    if (_checkForGameOverEnemy == 3)
    {
        state = BattleState.WON;
        EndBattle();
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.25f);

    randomIntEnemy = Random.Range(0, enemyPrefab.Length);
    GameObject enemyGO = Instantiate(enemyPrefab[randomIntEnemy], enemySpawn);
    enemyUnit = enemyGO.GetComponent<Unit>();

    if (_checkForGameOverEnemy == 1)
    { 
        Destroy(questionMarks[2]);

        if (randomIntEnemy == 0)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[0], middleSpawnEnemy);
        }
        else if (randomIntEnemy == 1)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[1], middleSpawnEnemy);
        }
        else if (randomIntEnemy == 2)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[2], middleSpawnEnemy);
        }
        else if (randomIntEnemy == 3)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[3], middleSpawnEnemy);
        }

    }

    if (_checkForGameOverEnemy == 2)
    {
        Destroy(questionMarks[3]);

        if (randomIntEnemy == 0)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[0], bottomSpawnEnemy);
        }
        else if (randomIntEnemy == 1)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[1], bottomSpawnEnemy);
        }
        else if (randomIntEnemy == 2)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[2], bottomSpawnEnemy);
        }
        else if (randomIntEnemy == 3)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[3], bottomSpawnEnemy);
        }
    }

    enemyHUD.SetHUD(enemyUnit);

    if (playerUnit.speed > enemyUnit.speed)
    {
        state = BattleState.PLAYERTURN;
        PlayerTurn();
    }

    else if (enemyUnit.speed > playerUnit.speed)
    {
        passButtonDamage.interactable = false;
        attackButton.interactable = false;
        healButton.interactable = false;
        passButtonResistance.interactable = false;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        state = BattleState.ENEMYTURN;
        StartCoroutine(EnemyTurn());
    }
}

IEnumerator PlayerDead()
{
    _checkForGameOverPlayer++;


    if (_checkForGameOverEnemy == 1)
    {
        if (randomIntPlayer == 0)
        {

        }
        else if (randomIntPlayer == 1)
        {

        }
        else if (randomIntPlayer == 2)
        {

        }
        else if (randomIntPlayer == 3)
        {

        }
    }

    if (_checkForGameOverPlayer == 3)
    {
        state = BattleState.LOST;
        EndBattle();
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.25f);

    randomIntPlayer = Random.Range(0, playerPrefab.Length);
    GameObject playerGO = Instantiate(playerPrefab[randomIntPlayer], playerSpawn);
    playerUnit = playerGO.GetComponent<Unit>();

    if (_checkForGameOverPlayer == 1)
    {
        Destroy(questionMarks[0]);

        if (randomIntPlayer == 0)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[0], middleSpawn);
        }
        else if (randomIntPlayer == 1)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[1], middleSpawn);
        }
        else if (randomIntPlayer == 2)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[2], middleSpawn);
        }
        else if (randomIntPlayer == 3)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[3], middleSpawn);
        }

    }

    if (_checkForGameOverPlayer == 2)
    {
        Destroy(questionMarks[1]);

        if (randomIntPlayer == 0)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[0], bottomSpawn);
        }
        else if (randomIntPlayer == 1)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[1], bottomSpawn);
        }
        else if (randomIntPlayer == 2)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[2], bottomSpawn);
        }
        else if (randomIntPlayer == 3)
        {
            Instantiate(icon[3], bottomSpawn);
        }

    }

    playerHUD.SetHUD(playerUnit);

    if (playerUnit.speed > enemyUnit.speed)
    {
        state = BattleState.PLAYERTURN;
        PlayerTurn();
    }

    else if (enemyUnit.speed > playerUnit.speed)
    {
        passButtonDamage.interactable = false;
        attackButton.interactable = false;
        healButton.interactable = false;
        passButtonResistance.interactable = false;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        state = BattleState.ENEMYTURN;
        StartCoroutine(EnemyTurn());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `SpriteRenderer` to render the icon, then you can use `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color` to access it's color, and your opacity value can be accessed via `Color.a`, which means *alpha*. 0 means it's transparent, 1 means it's full-visible. Here's my suggestion:

```cs
foreach (var g in icon)
{
    if (g == null) continue;
    var sprite = g.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    var color = sprite.color;
    sprite.color = new Color(color.r, color.g, color.b, 0)
}
```

Be careful that since it contains `GetComponent()`, it's not recommended to do like so in `Update()` function. Only do this when the event has "Actually" occured.

Comment: so how do i set this up so that the only icons that are transparent are the ones previously instantiated? for example, the game starts with 2 icons that should be at 100% opacity, and then if say the player dies, then his starting icon will turn transparent, and then the new one will spawn at 100% opacity and so on. I have no clue, any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: What are you meaning, "starting icon"? Sorry but I don't think I'm correctly understanding your question :(

Comment: so there two are characters to start, one on the player side, one on the enemy side. There is a mini icon of the characters to signify that they are on the battlefield and alive. If the player dies, then an icon of the next player character to come on the battlefield is instantiated, and the original icon of the player is turned down to 50% opacity to signify that he is dead. So now the player side has one slightly transparent icon representing the dead character, and a fully visible icon representing the new character on the player side of the battle field.